# vim regex that combines all items

Tags: regex, vim

I have a file in the following format

```
1 2472
1 664
2 2600
10 4135
10 5606
...
```

and I want to convert it to

```
1 2472 664
2 2600
10 4135 5606
...
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can combine items by executing this command:

```
:%s/\v(\d+\s)(.*\n\1.*)+/\=substitute(submatch(0),'\n'.submatch(1),' ','g')/
```

Comment: I have just created a vimgolf challenge. Let's see how many new approaches people can come up with. 
the url: http://vimgolf.com/challenges/587cab5a0740c90006000006

Answer (score 0):

With multiline support, you can go with:

```
^(\d+) (\d+)$[.\s]+?^\1 (\d+)
```

See it on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/kiaAlH/3).

The idea is to use backreferences to match two lines.

In vim's syntax, you'd write it as follows:

```
:%s/\_^\(\d*\) \(\d*\)\_$\_.*\_^\1 \(\d*\)/\1 \2 \3/
```

Comment: I have downvoted your post. Try at least to test your solution.

Comment: I tested it with vim version 7.3.547, and it works. Which version are you having issue with ?

Comment: Your solution works only for **<= 2 items**   . Try to test it for 3 or more and you will understand why I downvoted your answer !

Comment: you mean *<= 2 items* as in the question ?

Comment: OP did not limit the number of items + `...` !

Answer (score 0):

A reliable complete regex-based solution is also possible.

First, you must highlight non-repeated indices as follow:

`:%s/\(^\(\d\).\)\(\(.\|\(\n\)\1\)\+$\)/*\1\3/`

Next, must do the collapse of lines with:

`:%s/\n\(*.*$\)\@!\d\+ / /`

And lastly, remove `*` exceed character

`:%s/^*//g`

Best regards!